# SublimeText3 and MySQL - DB CLI mysql cannot be found

Tags: mysql, sublimetext3

I have a MySQL database running in my Mac terminal:

```
(base) Johns-MacBook-Pro-3:~ johndoe$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 8.0.20 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

---

Now I would like to start running commands from SublimeText3, in a file `sql.sql`, with:

```
show tables
```

In my `SQLToolsCOnnections.sublime-settings-SQLTool`s, I have:

```js
"Connection MySQL": {
  "type"    : "mysql",
  "host"    : "127.0.0.1",
  "port"    :  3306,
  "database": "giraffe",
  "username": "root",
  // use of password for MySQL is not recommended (use "defaults-extra-file" or "login-path")
  "password": "pwd",  // you will get a security warning in the output
  // "defaults-extra-file": "/path/to/defaults_file_with_password",  // use [client] or [mysql] section
  // "login-path": "your_login_path",  // login path in your ".mylogin.cnf"
  "default-character-set": "utf8",
  "encoding": "utf-8"
}
```

When I do Shift + Cmd + P, I get from Sublime:

```
"DB CLI mysql cannot be found"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is directly addressed in the [README](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SQLTools) under "*Using SQLTools with Mac OS X*". You need to enter the full path to the `mysql` binary in your `SQLTools.sublime-settings` file. To find the full path, open Terminal and type `which mysql`. Next, open **`Sublime Text → Preferences → Package Settings → SQLTools → Settings`** and add the following to the right side:

```js
{
    "cli": {
        "mysql": "/full/path/to/mysql"
    }
}
```

Save the file and the connection should work.

Comment: thank you, but where in `.sublime-settings`?  here ----> `"--login-path=\"{login-path}\"",`?

Comment: My mistake, the command should be `mysql`, not `mysqli`. I added additional instructions to my answer.